# VMware Server 2.0 - The VMware Infrastructure Web Service not responding

Tags: vmware, vmware-server

After installing VMware Server I get the following error when I try to access the VMware web-based server manager:

> The VMware Infrastructure Web Service
>   at "http://localhost:8222/sdk" is not
>   responding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go into the services manager and check that the **'VMware Host Agent'** service is running. If not, then start it and then try browsing to the site again.

Comment: How do we check if it is running? I have vmserver 2 installed on vista home premium 32bit

Comment: Administrative Tools > Services

Answer (score 3):

Vmware Hostd was not working for me either.

However, in trying to start the service it stopped automatically. Typically when this happens it is because there is an error in your config.xml.
C:\ProgramData\VMware\VMware Server\hostd\config.xml

In my case, checking the logs at:
C:\ProgramData\VMware\VMware Server

showed it erroring out after "Trying hostsvc".

Searching the config.xml for hostsvc showed references to several things, the first thing was the datastore. In checking my datastores.xml file:
C:\ProgramData\VMware\VMware Server\hostd\datastores.xml .

I found it full of all sorts of random characters instead of a properly formed XML document.

Renaming datastores.xml to datastorex.xml.bad allowed me to start the service. At which point I had to add back my datastores through the GUI.

Hopefully this will help someone else out. I did not find any other references in Google to this issue.

Comment: Thank you - my datastores.xml file was just empty. Renaming it let me start the host service, and then everything worked after that.

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing via "http://localhost:8222" without the /sdk.  You can also try the secure site via "https://localhost:8333".